# Trying to set properties on checkboxes in a for loop

Tags: winforms, powershell, loops, checkbox

I've been trying to find this by myself but I'm not entirely sure even how to phrase the question. Essentially what I'm doing here is taking an array of Names, and from that creating a checkbox for each name. Edit: I thought the code snippet below was working too but it looks like this might not be actually working?

```
New-object System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox | New-Variable -Name ("checkbox" + $_)
```

The main problem I'm having is this: How do I actually set the properties on these variable named checkboxes once they've been created? Essentially how to get the variable name for each iteration, then do the $checkbox.margin and such settings. I've posted my entire script below, it's very WIP and I know there's some other stuff that's weird but I'm planning to sort that out once I can fix this.

```
$form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$flowlayoutpanel = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.FlowLayoutPanel
$buttonOK = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button


$usernames = "andrew", "beth", "charlie", "dave", "james", "george"
$totalvalues = ($usernames.count)

$formsize = 85 + (30 * $totalvalues)
$flowlayoutsize = 10 + (30 * $totalvalues)
$buttonplacement = 40 + (30 * $totalvalues)

$form_Load = {
    0..$totalvalues|%{
        New-object System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox | New-Variable -Name ("checkbox" + $_)
        ('$checkbox' + $_).Margin = '10, 8, 0, 0'
        $checkbox.Margin = '10, 8, 0, 0'
        $checkbox.Name = 'checkbox' + $_
        $checkbox.Size = '200, 22'
        $checkbox.Text = "" + $usernames[$_]
        $checkbox.TextAlign = 'MiddleLeft'
        $flowlayoutpanel.Controls.Add($checkbox)
    }       
}


$form.Controls.Add($flowlayoutpanel)
$form.Controls.Add($buttonOK)
$form.AcceptButton = $buttonOK
$form.AutoScaleDimensions = '8, 17'
$form.AutoScaleMode = 'Font'
$form.ClientSize = "500 , $formsize"
$form.FormBorderStyle = 'FixedDialog'
$form.Margin = '5, 5, 5, 5'
$form.MaximizeBox = $False
$form.MinimizeBox = $False
$form.Name = 'form1'
$form.StartPosition = 'CenterScreen'
$form.Text = 'Form'
$form.add_Load($form_Load)

$flowlayoutpanel.BorderStyle = 'FixedSingle'
$flowlayoutpanel.Location = '48, 13'
$flowlayoutpanel.Margin = '4, 4, 4, 4'
$flowlayoutpanel.Name = 'flowlayoutpanel1'
$flowlayoutpanel.Size = "400, $flowlayoutsize"
$flowlayoutpanel.TabIndex = 1


$buttonOK.Anchor = 'Bottom, Right'
$buttonOK.DialogResult = 'OK'
$buttonOK.Location = "383, $buttonplacement"
$buttonOK.Margin = '4, 4, 4, 4'
$buttonOK.Name = 'buttonOK'
$buttonOK.Size = '100, 30'
$buttonOK.TabIndex = 0
$buttonOK.Text = '&OK'


$form.ShowDialog()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace your foreacheach loop with this code

```
$form_Load = {
    foreach($user in $usernames){
        $DynamicCheckBox = New-Variable -Name ("checkbox" + $user)
        $DynamicCheckBox = New-object System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox

        $DynamicCheckBox.Margin = '10, 8, 0, 0'
        $DynamicCheckBox.Name = 'checkbox' + $_
        $DynamicCheckBox.Size = '200, 22'
        $DynamicCheckBox.Text = "" + $user
        $DynamicCheckBox.TextAlign = 'MiddleLeft'
        $flowlayoutpanel.Controls.Add($DynamicCheckBox)
    }       
}
```

Comment: Thanks, if I do it this way, what would be the best way to check the status of the checkboxes once the OK button is hit? Or should that be a separate question?

Comment: Plase make a seprate question. And mark this one as an answer if this solved your problem